# Python BZ2 IOError: invalid data stream

Tags: python, python-2.7, bzip2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TTRC_main.py", line 309, in <module>
    updater.start()
  File "TTRC_main.py", line 36, in start
    newFileData = bz2.BZ2File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Toontown Rewritten/temp/phase_7.mf.bz2"," rb").read()
IOError: invalid data stream
```

The code to retrieve file I'm getting that's giving me this error is:

```
newFileComp = urllib.URLopener()
newFileComp.retrieve("http://kcmo-1.download.toontownrewritten.com/content/phase_7.mf.bz2", "C:/Program Files (x86)/Toontown Rewritten/temp/phase_7.mf.bz2")
```

What do I do to fix this error? Its not really descriptive. (to me)

Answer (score 4):

Could the issue be occuring because of the `extra space`in the file mode? -

```
newFileData = bz2.BZ2File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Toontown Rewritten/temp/phase_7.mf.bz2"," rb").read()
```

Try this -

```
newFileData = bz2.BZ2File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Toontown Rewritten/temp/phase_7.mf.bz2","rb").read()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the files were not in .bz2 format.

Comment: For me the bz2 file contained other files in addition of the csv I was expecting.

Comment: same here - I forgot to use the -k option with bunzip2 to retain the original file and accidentally referred to the uncompressed filename.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure file is bz2 format.
2. Make sure the read and write actions are the same "r","w" or "rb","wb"
3. Like Anand said, no space in "rb".