# `OSError: Invalid data stream` to load bz2 pickle [.pbz2] serialized pd.DataFrame object (Python 3.6.2)

Tags: python, pandas, compression, pickle, bz2

```
## Versions
print("Versions", "____________", sys.version.replace("\n","\t"), pd.__version__, sep="\n")
#Versions
#____________
#3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59)  #[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
#0.21.1

# How I wrote the object
def write_object(obj, path, compression="bz2", protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL, **args):
    """
    Extensions:
    pickle ==> .pkl
    gzipped-pickle ==> .pgz
    bzip2-pickle ==> .pbz2
    """
    if compression is not None:
        if compression == "bz2":
            f = bz2.BZ2File(path, "wb")
        if compression == "gzip":
            f = gzip.GzipFile(path, "wb")
    else:
        f = open(path, "wb")
    pickle.dump(obj, f, protocol=protocol, **args)
    f.close()

# How I'm trying to read it back in
path = "./Data/objects/counts.tsv.pbz2"
write_object(df, path) #df = pd.DataFrame of ints

f = bz2.open(path, "rb")
df_loaded = pickle.load(f)
f.close()


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-13-04a37c035163> in <module>()
#       1 path = "./Data/objects/counts.tsv.pbz2"
#       2 f = bz2.open(path, "rb")
# ----> 3 pickle.load(f)

# ~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/bz2.py in peek(self, n)
#     170             # always returns at least one byte (except at EOF), independent
#     171             # of the value of n
# --> 172             return self._buffer.peek(n)
#     173 
#     174     def read(self, size=-1):

# ~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/_compression.py in readinto(self, b)
#      66     def readinto(self, b):
#      67         with memoryview(b) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
# ---> 68             data = self.read(len(byte_view))
#      69             byte_view[:len(data)] = data
#      70         return len(data)

# ~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/_compression.py in read(self, size)
#     101                 else:
#     102                     rawblock = b""
# --> 103                 data = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock, size)
#     104             if data:
#     105                 break

# OSError: Invalid data stream
```

The file is a `285.5 MB` tab-delimited table of integers with `~1.5M columns` and `~100 rows`.  The `gzipped` file size is `42.4 MB` and the bz2-zipped pickled `pd.DataFrame` is `34.2 MB`. It takes 45 minutes to load into a `pd.DataFrame` which is why I am serializing.

**Is there a limit to how large the objects can be that are pickled in this way?**

The reason why I ask is my other count table that I processed in the exact same way is opening perfectly.  The file size for this is `unprocessed .tsv = 148.9 MB`,  `gzipped = 24.8 MB`, and `bz2-zipped pickled .pbz2 = 19.8 MB`.

The only similar question but the answer does not help:
[Python BZ2 IOError: invalid data stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882145/python-bz2-ioerror-invalid-data-stream)

Comment: Also, just realized there's a `.to_pickle` and `read_pickle` in `pandas` which I will use from now on for `pd.DataFrame` objects but I'm still curious why this is corrupted :/

Comment: You are trying to load the object on the same python file you dumped it? As fas as I know, to load a python object with pickle, the class of the object should be defined when you are trying to load it, so pickle know how that data should be structured inside the program